# Can we apply the sandwich theorem if superior and inferior sequences tend to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If $\lim_{{n}\to{\infty}} \hspace{1 mm} f(n) = \infty$ and $\lim_{{n}\to{\infty}} \hspace{1 mm} h(n)= \infty$ and $f(n) \le g(n) \le h(n)$. Can we say $\lim_{{n}\to{\infty}} \hspace{1 mm} g(n) = \infty$?

Comment: Yes, this means that $f$ and $h$ will "escort" $g$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, this follows from $f(n)\leq g(n)$, you don't even need the sandwich theorem

Comment: $n$ are natural numbers, $x$ are reals, intentional?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! Actually you don't need the upper part even.

The proof is simple too, if you just state the definition of divergence to infinity.